# restore unix command line parameters after sourcing a parameter accepting profile

Tags: shell, unix

Platforms are AIX 7.1 and HP-UX Itanium 11.31, Korn shell.  Most of our scripts source in a main profile to set up needed environment variables.  A new requirement is the selective sourcing of another profile from within the main profile.  The second profile needs to accept parameters.  Unfortunately, when we source that second profile, the system variable ($*) which stores the original command line parameters gets overwritten.  For example:

Call without need for second profile: `./script my original parms`
Main profile does not source the second profile.
`$*` contains `my original parms`.  We're good here.

Call with source of second profile: `./script my second original parms`
Main profile sources second profile as:  `. ./secondProfile second profile parms`
`$*` contains `second profile parms`.  Uh oh.

So, we effectively lose `my second original parms` in the second version of the main script call.  Is there a way we can save/restore those original parameters, or be able reference them via some other method after sourcing the second profile?

Comment: Can you not just assign `$*` to another variable before you call the second script and then use that variable instead?

Comment: and recall that any place in your code you reset the `$*` values with `set -- arg1 arg2 ..` and now the shell arg `$1` will equal "arg1", etc. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere you'll need to store the params. Use an array:

```
set -A params "$@"
```

It's important to use `"$@"` instead of `$*` -- the former will preserve any arguments with whitespace.

To restore the positional parameters:

```
set -- "${params[@]}"
./script "$@"
```

Comment: set -A params "$@" dit not work for me but params="$@" worked.

Comment: what's your shell?'

Comment: then you should use a regular array: `params=( "$@" )`. In bash, `-A` is an invalid option for `set`. My answer is for ksh, as required by the question. So, if you are my downvoter, you may want to reconsider it.